# Excel: Check if Cell contains one of many substrings. Show substring if True

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently following method described here: https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things with a few alterations (to compensate for variable number of substrings).

Code is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(OFFSET(Categories!A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1),[@String])))>0
```

What I'd like is instead of a "TRUE" or "FALSE" output, is to output the substring that matches. "first encountered" substring would be fine, or "all substrings separated by a comma" or anything like that.

Not really sure where to start, or even if it's possible with Excel formulas.

Answer (score 1):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/SEARCH(Substring_List,String),Substring_List)`

is probably the most efficient, though you should know that, if more than one entry from *Substring_List* is found within *String*, this set-up will return that which occurs latest within that list.

Regards